# How to set the cursor position when dwm starts?

Tags: dwm

I’m trying to find out how dwm decides the initial position of the mouse cursor, after it started.
I looked in dwm.c for a while, but my knowledge of C and X11 doesn’t cut it.

What I want to do is to place the cursor in my primary monitor. Now it is created on the other one, causing it to be initially selected. When I first start a terminal or something else (using the keyboard), it opens in the wrong monitor. It’s a minor annoyance, but also a pretext to learn something :)

I’m not sure if dwm should be responsible for that, or xorg is maybe? Is dwm aware of the primary output set with xrandr?

**Update**

I tried to use XWarpPointer() in dwm.c, in main() just before run() is called. This way I managed to move the pointer to the center of the screen, but the wrong one :)

**Update 2**

As suggested in the comments, it could be something wrong in my xrandr setup. Here it is:

```
xrandr —output DP-0 —rotate left
xrandr —output DP-0 —left-of DP-4
xrandr —output DP-4 —pos 1080x160
xrandr —output DP-4 —primary
```

**Edit:** dwm initializes DP-0 first (where the status bar appears first). Though if I disconnect the mouse and reboot, dwm behaves correctly and the focus is on DP-4 (eventhough DP-0 is initialized first).

**Update 3**

As a test I started i3wm instead of dwm. The pointer is initialized in the center of the screen (DP-4) as expected and all is fine.

Comment: dwm will default to the primary screen (monitor), see https://dwm.suckless.org/multi-monitor/

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes, I recall reading this when I setup the second monitor, however looks like the mouse position overrides it (I tried disconnecting the mouse and it does default to the primary screen).

Comment: Mouse is a red herring; which screen is initialised first (where does dwm's status bar first appear)?

Comment: @jasonwryan Seems to appear first on the secondary screen

Comment: So, dwm/X thinks that is your primary: you can fix that with xrandr.

Comment: @jasonwryan Not really, I’m already using xrandr —primary in my xinitrc. Also confirmed by the output of xrandr (shows the * on the right screen). If i mess up a bit with xrandr, giving a wrong pos argument, I end up having the pointer initialized on the primary screen. This way the primary screen keeps the focus.

Comment: dwm knows only about screens and focus. I can only surmise that there is something in your xrandr setup that is off.

Comment: @jasonwryan Well possible, I updated the post with the xrandr setup.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which display is initialised first.

Comment: @jasonwryan Done.

Comment: And if you move the DP-4 commands (primary) above the others?

Comment: @jasonwryan If I move both, the —pos has no effect, but the pointer is initialized on the primary screen, which in turn keeps the focus. I have to move —pos after --left-of to be effective, but this results in “wrong” pointer position again.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely the xrandr setup. Keep playing with it; you do need the correct order. The man page will do the rest.

Comment: @jasonwryan I updated the post. i3 seems to have no problem with this xrandr setup. Nevertheless I will read the man page once again and try a different setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same problem using dwm-6.2 in Ubuntu 20.04 and fixed it by forcing the mouse cursor to move to the desired monitor using the X11 automation tool (installed with many distros by default).
Just add the following line to whichever script starts `dwm` right before it's invocation:

```
xdotool mousemove 2000 200
```

Replace the values with the appropriate x y coordinates where 0 0 is at the top left corner of the leftmost screen (the virtual screen).

One tip from `man dwm`:

> ```
>   Mod1-, Focus previous screen, if any.
>   Mod1-. Focus next screen, if any.
>   Mod1-Shift-,
>          Send focused window to previous screen, if any.
>   Mod1-Shift-.
>          Send focused window to next screen, if any.
> ```

So, to easily move between monitors use:

```
[Alt}+[.]
[Alt]+[,]
```